# My custom RxDelegateProxy immediately disposing

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I have some third party library that has delegate methods. But I like using RX so I should create RxDelegateProxy to receive delegate's callbacks via RX.

Here my custom DelegateProxy class:

```
extension Reactive where Base:GalleryController {

  var selectedImages:Observable<(GalleryController, [Image])> {
    let proxy = RxGalleryDelegateProxy.createProxy(for: self.base)
    return proxy.imageSubject.asObservable()
  }

}

private class RxGalleryDelegateProxy: DelegateProxy<GalleryController, GalleryControllerDelegate>, DelegateProxyType, GalleryControllerDelegate {

  private var _imageSubject: PublishSubject<(GalleryController, [Image])>?

  public weak fileprivate(set) var galleryController: GalleryController?

  internal var imageSubject: PublishSubject<(GalleryController, [Image])> {
    if let subject = _imageSubject {
      return subject
    }

    let subject = PublishSubject<(GalleryController, [Image])>()
    _imageSubject = subject

    return subject
  }

  static func currentDelegate(for object: GalleryController) -> GalleryControllerDelegate? {
    return object.delegate
  }

  static func setCurrentDelegate(_ delegate: GalleryControllerDelegate?, to object: GalleryController) {
    object.delegate = delegate
  }

  static func registerKnownImplementations() {
    self.register { RxGalleryDelegateProxy(parentObject: $0) }
  }

  private init(parentObject: GalleryController) {
    self.galleryController = castOrFatalError(parentObject)
    super.init(parentObject: parentObject, delegateProxy: RxGalleryDelegateProxy.self)
  }

  func galleryController(_ controller: GalleryController, didSelectImages images: [Image]) {
    if let subject = _imageSubject {
      subject.on(.next((controller, images)))
    }

    self._setForwardToDelegate(galleryController(controller, didSelectImages: images), retainDelegate: true)
  }

  deinit {
    _imageSubject?.on(.completed)
  }

}
```

In my UIViewController I subscribe with:

```
final class PhotoLibraryViewController: UIViewController {

  private let _bag = DisposeBag()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let gallery = GalleryController()
    present(gallery, animated: true, completion: nil)

    gallery.rx.selectedImages
      .debug("--------")
      .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
      .subscribe(onNext: { (controller, images) in
        print("\(images)")
      }, onError: { (error) in
        DDLogError("Error:\n\(error)")
      })
      .disposed(by: _bag)

  }

}
```

But all I get in console output via .debug("--------") is:

```
2018-01-09 20:05:14.814: -------- -> subscribed
2018-01-09 20:05:14.817: -------- -> Event completed
2018-01-09 20:05:14.817: -------- -> isDisposed
```

So my object is immediately disposing just after creation. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Can you provide more context? I suspect both *proxy* and *_bag* are getting released too soon.

Comment: Hi! Updated. _bag is just private let _bag = DisposeBag(). But what about proxy?

Comment: ok, then probably proxy's *deinit* method is getting called once the *proxy* variable is out of scope. try moving it into a greater scope and see whether it makes any difference.

Comment: I'll try. But I believed that bag during retain subscription will hold proxydelegate.

Comment: Nope. It didn't help. (

Answer (score 0):

Your `gallery` object is created inside `viewDidLoad()`, so once `viewDidLoad()` is completed, the `deinit` method from `gallery` is called and it is disposed.

Move your `gallery` object out of the `viewDidLoad()`:

```
final class PhotoLibraryViewController: UIViewController {

  private let _bag = DisposeBag()
  let gallery = GalleryController()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    present(gallery, animated: true, completion: nil)

    gallery.rx.selectedImages
      .debug("--------")
      .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
      .subscribe(onNext: { (controller, images) in
        print("\(images)")
      }, onError: { (error) in
        DDLogError("Error:\n\(error)")
      })
      .disposed(by: _bag)

  }

}
```

Comment: This should be correct answer as you are creating the instance of `GalleryController` inside `viewDidLoad` method so once the `viewDidLoad` is completed the instance of `GalleryController` will also deinitialised.